# Haskell Returns only Numerator of Division (Sometimes)

Tags: math, haskell

I have two functions:

```
calctvd :: [Perk] -> [Perk] -> Perk -> Double
calctvd ps fs p = (fromIntegral(tvn) / fromIntegral(points)) :: Double
    where
        tvn = calctvn ps fs p
        points = length $ [i | i <- perkAndPreqs ps p, i `notElem` fs]
```

The above function always succeeds in returning the double that I would expect.  The important line is the division `(fromIntegral(tvn) / fromIntegral(points))`.  The function calctvn (not shown here) and the variable points are always integers, so fromIntegral() is necessary.

```
updatetvd :: [Perk] -> [Perk] -> [Perk]
updatetvd [] _ = []
updatetvd ps fs
    --If p is in the list of elements already taken, then do not update it
    | p `elem` fs = [p] ++ updatetvd (tail ps) fs
    --Otherwise, update the tvd value
    | otherwise = [PerkImpl (tvd, school, skill, name, def, preqstr, pref)] ++ updatetvd (tail ps) fs
    where
        p = head ps
        PerkImpl (_, school, skill, name, def, preqstr, pref) = p
        tvd = calctvd ps fs p
```

Essentially, this second function should just insert the value of the first function into a list.  However, it only inserts the numerator of the term `(fromIntegral(tvn) / fromIntegral(points))`.  I proved this by changing that line in calctvd to `3 / fromIntegral(points)`.  With this, calctvd still returned the correctly divided double, whereas updatetvd always inserted a value of 3.0.  It is as if Haskell does not evaluate the denominator if calctvd is called from inside updatetvd.

Update 1:

However, it appears that this oddity relies on some complexity in the above two functions.  I tried to break it down into a simple example:

```
testcalctvd :: Double
testcalctvd = fromIntegral(3) / fromIntegral(4) :: Double

testupdatetvd :: Double
testupdatetvd = testcalctvd
```

However, both testcalctvd and testupdatetvd return the correct 0.75.

Update 2:

Here is an example straight from Terminal, using the test term `3 / fromIntegral(points)`:

```
> calctvd initial [] i17
0.6    {This is 3/5, because i17 has 5 points}
> updatetvd initial []
[...3.0...]    {This is just the numerator 3}
```

Update 3:

Here is the perkAndPreqs function, which is probably the culprit, but I am not sure how much sense it will make:

```
--Take a perk and return a list of that perk and all of its pre-requisites
perkAndPreqs :: [Perk] -> Perk -> [Perk]
perkAndPreqs _ NULL = []
perkAndPreqs ps p = [p] ++ perkAndPreqs ps preq
    where
        PerkImpl (_, _, _, _, _, preqstring, _) = p
        preq = perkIdentifier preqstring ps
```

Comment: Just a note: for your `calctvd` function, you don't need the `:: Double` at the end or any of the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, I added that only in the hope that it would help Haskell figure out what it should be doing.

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't just always hitting the ```p `elem` fs``` case for some reason?

Comment: I am certain that it is not.  It is indeed updating the values.  By default, all values are set to 1.  In the test case I gave above, it updates all of the correct terms with a 3.0.  The problem is just that it did not divide the 3.0 by the fromIntegral(points) term!  In the non test case, it correctly updates the values to the numerator of the tvd number.

Comment: Show us your definition of `perkAndPreqs`.

Comment: I am trying to simplify it to a point that anyone could plug it into Haskell, while still maintaining the oddity.

Comment: @kienjakenobi: Well, clearly `calctvd` is a pure function. So if it's giving you unexpected outputs when called from `updatetvd`, it must be because you're not giving it the expected inputs. You could try using `Debug.Trace` to check what you're passing to it.

Comment: @dave4420: Apparently it does have to do with the points variable.  If I change that to a constant, then both calctvd and updatetvd produce the correct result.

Comment: @kienjakenobi Next check whether `perkAndPreqs` behaves as expected; if it doesn't, check whether `perkIdentifier` behaves as expected.

Comment: @dave4420: When I call them myself, they do behave correctly.  This is the confusing bit.

Comment: @kienjakenobi When you call them yourself, do you call them with `p` as the first element of `ps`? hammar's suggestion of using [Debug.Trace](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Debug-Trace.html) is a good one.

Comment: @dave4420: While it is true that I sometimes do not call them with p == head ps, this should not be important.  They work properly both with p == head ps and with p /= head ps.  The functions are built to find the right perk p in the set ps and return the corresponding value.

Comment: Aha!  You were right.  The problem is what updatetvd is being fed during its recursions.  The ps variable is becoming increasingly shorter.  However, calctvd and perkAndPreqs require that it remains constant.  This explains why I did not see this behavior when calling it myself: There is no recursion which decreases the size of ps.  The fact that it was returning only the numerator is an odd result of the ordering of ps and the pre-requisites of its elements.

Comment: @kienjakenobi: In that case, your function can be rewritten using `map` since it's doing the same thing to every element of `ps`. Doing your own recursion can be error-prone (as you've noticed), so you should prefer to use higher-order functions when appropriate.

Comment: @hammar: That is a brilliant idea!  I am still trying to get myself into the functional programming mindset, and I did not think of this.  After rethinking a few of the helper function, my updatetvd function is a one-liner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you call `calctvd` by hand, the `p` parameter you pass is not also the first element of the `ps` parameter. But when `calctvd` is called from `updatetvd`, `p = head ps`.

I cannot be sure, because you've shown us neither failing test cases nor the definition of `perkAndPreqs` (if `points` is being miscalculated as `1`, the clue as to why is likely to be in `perkAndPreqs`).